# How to add L1-regularization to one hidden layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

There have been some answers about adding L1-regularization to the Weights of one hidden. However what I want is not only the sparseness of Weight, but also the sparseness of the representation of one hidden layer. What I want is something like the code below. Is it feasible to be realized, or I need only to add L1-regularization on the Weights?

```
import tensorflow as tf
...
**HIDDEN** = tf.contrib.layers.dense(input_layer, n_nodes)
...
loss = meansq #or other loss calcuation
l1_regularizer = tf.contrib.layers.l1_regularizer(scale=0.005, scope=None)
regularization_penalty = tf.contrib.layers.apply_regularization(l1_regularizer, **HIDDEN**)

regularized_loss = loss + regularization_penalty
```

This idea is from the sparse representation of the book Deep Learning written by Goodfellow and Bengio.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `tf.contrib.layers`, the `fully_connected` function accepts `weights_regularizer` argument, so your code should look like thus

```
l1 = tf.contrib.layers.l1_regularizer(scale=0.005, scope=None)
hidden = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(inputs, n_nodes, weights_regularizer=l1)
```

That said, `tf.contrib.layers` has been mostly moved to the core API, so you should be using `tf.layers.dense` instead with `kernel_regularizer` argument.

The code above will regularize the weights in the layer. If you want to regularize both weights and the layer output, you can use the same `tf.contrib.layers.l1_regularizer` or create a different one with different parameters. Something like this should work for you:

```
l1 = tf.contrib.layers.l1_regularizer(scale=0.005, scope=None)
hidden = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(inputs, n_nodes, weights_regularizer=l1)
hidden_reg = l1(hidden)
```

Comment: For `y=Wx`, your method can just guarantee some entries of `W` is nearly zero. But it can't conduce `y` is sparse for the theory of sparse activity representation.

Comment: Well, if you want to regularize `y`, you can just pass the layer output to the regularization function. `tf.contrib.layers.l1_regularizer` returns a function, so just do that. I will update my answer to reflect.

Comment: I think that may work. I guess the l1-reg on a hidden layer would make all entries of a few columns of the `Weight` near zeor, then realize sparse representation. Look forward for your further answer.